# Verify http response from grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I need to verify the validity of 4000+ urls that i fetch from a web service, before adding them in a javascript file. 
I am using a grunt task to make some cleanup operation on these urls, and I also would like to verify that each url is returning 200 HTTP Status code before adding them to the js file, so within the grunt task.

In the example, based on the result of the valiate_url task I need to modify the urlToProxy array

**For clarity the whole task I want to build is:**

1. Read urls from an API and write to file
2. Cleanup the url list (another task, not in the example code)
3. Validate urls to check if the server respond with a 200
4. Write url to a file containing a simple js array

Any idea / suggestion on how can I do it ?

```
grunt.initConfig({
...

    exec: {
      validate_url: {
        cmd: function(url){
          return 'curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://' + url + '" -o /dev/null';
        },
        callback: function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          if(stdout==200){
            // YES 200 returned
          } else {
            // OOPS NO 200 returned
          }
        }
      }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('readconfig', 'reads the configuration', function() {

    var urls = grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/proxyUrls.json');
    var urlsToProxy = urls.record.split('\n');

    for(var i = urlsToProxy.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        grunt.task.run('exec:validate_url:' + 'urlsToProxy[i]);
    }
}
```

proxyUrl.js content

```
{ "record": "audentes.com\nfortuna.com\niuvat.com\n...\nwww.google.com" }
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Comment: yes, It is already a good direction, I need now to modify the input array based on the validate_url,that is more difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with curl and [exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec) in Grunt.

Below you can find a complete code example. Don't forget to create a package.json. Running this should go like this:

```
$npm init
$npm install grunt-exec --save
$grunt
```

This should go in your `Gruntfile.js`

```
module
    .exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt
            .loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec'); // register the exec task (from package.json)
        grunt
            .initConfig({
                exec: {
                  validate_url: {
                    cmd: function(url){
                        console
                            .log('validate: ' + url); // log that we are validating
                        return 'curl -sL -w "%{http_code}|%{url_effective}\\n" "http://www.google.com" -o /dev/null -m 5'; // the actual curl. Note the -m 5, this is a 5 second timeout. Also note the -w, this is the writeout which we will split later
                    },
                    callback: function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                        var stdoutSplit = stdout
                                            .split('|');
                        if(stdoutSplit[0]==200){ // 200 status is returned
                            console
                                .log('YES 200, the requested url was: ' + stdoutSplit[1]); // YES 200 returned
                        } else {
                            console
                                .log('Crap, no 200, the requested url was: ' + stdoutSplit[1]);// OOPS NO 200 returned
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
            });

        grunt
            .registerTask('default', function() {
                grunt
                    .file
                    .readJSON('proxyUrls.json')
                    .record.split('\n')
                    .forEach(function(val){
                        if(val !== ''){
                            grunt.task.run('exec:validate_url:' + val);
                        }
                    });
            });
    };
```

**Note**:
Try it from your own command line: `curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RPSbdNgR" -o /dev/null`

Comment: thanks Bob, it is already good, I am struggling to modify the input list as a result of the validation, I'll add more info in the question

Comment: @fram can you share an example of proxyUrls.json here http://pastebin.com/? Doesn't have to be all the domains and can be fake ones it's more that we can go end-to-end

Comment: I added it in the description, the structure is very simple

Comment: @fram this is the whole code... That kinda deserves a +1 and a green tick in the box, don't you think ;-)

Comment: Nice, but I still not see how I can obtain the full list of valid url in a variable, I mean I need to do other operation with this validated url list not just logging if an url is valid. The problem is that the url is not passed in the callback

Comment: @fram, you know what, if you accept my answer I will add the url in the callback...

Comment: ahah you are a funny generous guy, don't bother help me further

Comment: @fram dude, Stackoverflow is not for having people do the work for you. SO is to have people help you with questions.

Comment: @fram see the update, Curl now includes the location too

Comment: I know what SO is for, sometimes, rewards and bedges seems more important than giving help